# Login limit attempts in C#

Tags: c#

Im currently working on limiting the login attempts in my Login Form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int attempt = 1;
    int rAttempt = 2;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost; Username=root; Password=; database = logbook");

// ...
// Login Button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (attempt < 3) 
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * FROM tbl_enduser where Username = '" + 
                           lgUsername.Text + "' and Password = '" + lgPassword.Text + "' ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Logged in successfully!");
                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password");
                MessageBox.Show(rAttempt + "attempts remaining");
                rAttempt--;
            }
        } 
        else if(attempt == 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Limit of attempts reached!");
            lgUsername.Enabled = false;
            lgPassword.Enabled = false;
            this.Close();
        }
        attempt++;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Running the project and not matching any data in my `tbl_enduser` until the attempt limit reached is working fine, even not matching the first attempt and matching it in the second attempt is also working fine.

The problem is that in the last attempt, even if I input data that match a data in my `tbl_enduser` it doesn't go to `Form2`, instead it shows that the limit reached eventhough I inputted the right data matched to my `tbl_enduser`.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: Yes, the person above beat me to it.  But you should really never use that kind of sql command for such a commonly used area like logins....you are going to get burnt.  Use a dedicated query, or at least parameters in your command text.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to ensure your `DataTable` is being properly filled? More than likely something is off with the SQL query based on how it is being dynamically constructed. As others have noted, you are using a particularly vulnerable implementation and it is prone to errors (and worse).

Comment: The core issue is your attempt counter logic. Try debugging and checking the values of your variables to see if they are what you expect. The rest of the code has multiple other problems, though they aren't the cause of this specific issue.

Comment: Can you tell me what do I need to change to make my query not vulnerable to SQL iniection? I mean how will I do that parameterized queries?

Comment: @SamAxe I copy pasted the codes, Im sorry for the monstrous code formatting

Comment: @germi's answer is correct.  However, this is something you could have easily determined for yourself had you just set a breakpoint and done some very basic debugging.

Comment: @Herohtar if the values of variables are the problem then why is it working if I match immediately in the first attempt, even not matching it the first attempt then matching it the second attempt? And then why in the last attempt it goes to else if statement instead of if statement eventhough I matched it?

Comment: Try doing some debugging by stepping through your code and see what happens. It's a very basic problem.

Comment: Your suggestions are too much for a beginner like me. I don't have that much of time to explore MVS that's why I can't spend a time knowing such thing like debugger tool. So I spend my time getting a pen and a paper as I thought that it was all about the logic. That's why I analyzed them and managed to get and fixed it. But anyway thank you for the answers, it might help me next time.

Comment: Debugging is a very important aspect of programming. If you are going to continue writing code it is *vital* that you learn how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you start with `attempt = 1` and you increase it on each try, you only really get two tries:

- after the first try, `attempt` will be `2`, which is less than `3`, so
- your second try checks again, but sets `attempt` to `3`
- your third try now is no longer `< 3`, so you get the message that the limit's been reached

The solution would be to set `attempt` to `0` at first.

Problems like these can be very easily solved by using the [Viusal Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019). Now would be a great time to learn to use it. It's an invaluable tool for any developer.

Comment: I change the value of `attempt` to `0` and it does work when the MessageBox tells that `1 attempt remaining` then matching. But I tried to run it again and intended not matching until the MessageBox tells that limit reached and will close, before that the MessageBox tells 0 attempts left so I thought changing the `rAttempt` to `3` will work but it just lead me back to my problem

Comment: @Enthusiast I suggest you try stepping through your code with the debugger. You should quickly be able to see where you got mixed up.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I started using MVSC just recently. So what do you mean by debugger? Is that in the Debug > Start with Debugging?

Comment: In my answer there is a link with a tutorial on how to use the debugger. I suggest you give that a look and then try it out on your own code.